# Javascript - Override function imported from another file

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have a JS file that's being used on many VueJS components, this file has the following structure:

```
export const saver = () => {
  const prepareData = () => {
    // Empty function that I want to override on components only when it is necessary
  }

  const save = () => {
    prepareData()

    /* Logic to save data */
  }

  return {
    save,
    prepareData
  }
}

export default saver
```

This is how I import this file on Vue components:

```
<script>
import Saver from '@/utils/saver'
setup(props) {
  const saver = Saver()
  /** This is my approach so far....obviously is not working **/
  saver.prepareData = () => {
    console.log('It works!! Add here your extra logic...')
  }
  /***********************************************************/
  return {
    ...toRefs(saver)
  }
}
</script>
```

I'm using the new composition API, the `save` function is called in the template, inside a button:

```
<button @click="save()" type="submit">
```

My goal is to override the function `prepareData` only in the components that need to add some extra logic before submitting data to the backend. My approach so far was trying to override the function inside the components like this(inside the Vue Component that I need to override the function):

```
saver.prepareData = () => {
  console.log('It works!! Add here your extra logic...')
}
```

Any ideas?? :)) Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the Proxy API help in this case? You can check the documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Comment: @AbrarHossain Unfortunately no because Saver is not an object....

Comment: But the variable saver holds the value as returned from your function Saver which returns an object literal. So I don't understand that point.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be that the `Saver` class retains the internal `prepareData` method.

I think the simplest way to deal with it is to pass the function during creation

```js
export const Saver = (prepareData) => {
  const save = () => {
    prepareData && prepareData()

    /* Logic to save data */
  }

  return {
    save
  }
}

export default Saver
```

the downside is that you will need to have the method ready when you're calling `new Saver()`.

Another option is to use a `ref` for the `prepareData` method:

```js
import { ref } from "vue"
export const saver = () => {
  const prepareData = ref(null)

  const save = () => {
    prepareData.value && prepareData.value()

    /* Logic to save data */
  }

  return {
    save,
    prepareData
  }
}

export default saver
```

Then you should be able to...

```js
  saver.prepareData.value = () => {
    console.log('It works!! Add here your extra logic...')
  }
```

(note the use of `value` when it comes to `ref`)